# Could not load type error

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

***Hello everyone***,

***I'm trying to develop a facebook game but i'm pretty new at this subject. 
When i  debug at visual studio, page appearing without errors but when i publish it to my website that error page appraring.***

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Xandra.index'.

Source Error: 
 Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="Xandra.index" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Source File: /Apps/Web/Xandra/Index.aspx    Line: 1 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

***And my source code is:***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Facebook;
using Facebook.Web;
using Facebook.Session;

namespace Xandra
{
    public partial class index : Facebook.Web.CanvasIFrameBasePage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            CanvasSession fs = new Facebook.Session.FBMLCanvasSession(Config.APIKey, Config.Secret);
            base.RequireLogin = true;
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            long uid = (long)base.Api.Users.GetInfo().uid;
            Button1.Text = uid.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you deploy all proper assembly files (/bin) as well ?